# MYSQL query with variables that may not be set

Tags: mysql

I have a PHP file  which is taking in seven variables like so:

```
 $name=$_REQUEST['membername'];
 $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
 $dob=$_REQUEST['dob'];
 $gender=$_REQUEST['gender'];
 $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
 $county=$_REQUEST['county'];
 $IP=$_REQUEST['IP'];
```

Some of these will not be set. What I want to do is construct a query which will search the members table such that if only $email and $dob are set it will only search by $email and $dob, ignoring the others. Or if only $phone, $name, and $gender are set, it will search those three columns only.

Is there an easier method than constructing a big block of if isset functions covering all possible permutations?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to search on a field, pass NULL for the parameter and structure your WHERE clause something like...

```
WHERE 
( (@parameter1 IS NULL) OR (column1 = @parameter1) )
AND 
( (@parameter2 IS NULL) OR (column2 = @parameter2) )
```

I don't spend much time in MYSQL so the syntax is probably a bit off but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you use parameters to push values into the query...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE name = COALESCE(@p1, name) 
   OR  email = COALESCE(@p2, email)
   OR  dob = COALESCE(@p3, dob)
   ...
```

...

If you construct a query string in PHP you can, instead, take another tack:

```
 function AddWhere(&$where, $dbFieldName, $fieldValue)
 {
      if ($fieldValue <> "")
      {
         if (strlen($fieldName) >  0)
             $fieldName .= " AND ";

         $fieldname .= '(' + $dbFieldName + ' = \'' + $fieldValue + '\')'
      }
 }
```

Then, when you're retrived the variables, build a SQL statement thusly

```
 $whereClause = ''
 AddWhere($whereClause, 'name', $name)
 AddWhere($whereClause, 'email', $email)
 AddWhere($whereClause, 'dob', $dob)
 ...
 IF (strlen($whereClause) > 0)
 {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ' + $whereClause

    ...  etc
 }
```

(I'm not great at PHP, so the syntax may be somewhat screwed up).

Comment: I'm not using parameters, just variables like '$county'

Comment: So how do you get the values into the query:  do you compose one long query string in PHP?